# ¿Como llenar los campos de JFrame almacenados en MySQL utilizando Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transacciones

mi pregunta es **como puedo llenar los campos de mi `JFrame` con los datos almacenados en mi bbdd utilizando hibernate?**
Es decir, selecciono una fila de mi `JTable`, obtengo su id y al precionar un boton **editar** se habre un form que tendria todos los campos llenos con los datos que se encuentran mi bbdd MySQL.

Este es el formulario que quiero llenar al seleccionar una fila de mi JTable pero no logro hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que utilizo en mi clase **OperacionesClientes** para obtener el dato del cliente es:

```
public List<Clientes> obtenerCliente(Short idcliente){
        this.iniciarOperacion();
        String consulta = "FROM Clientes as C WHERE C.clientesidCliente = :idcliente";
        List<Clientes> clienteObtenido = this.session.createQuery(consulta).setParameter("idcliente", idcliente).list();
        return clienteObtenido;
    }
```

Dentro de mi JFrame realizo el siguiente metodo para traer los datos y llenar los campos:

```
/**
     * Llena los campos del form cliente extraidos de la base de datos.
     *
     * @param idCli Recibe como parametro un tipo Short que es el perteneciente al idcliente.
     */
    private void obtener(Short idCli) {
        try {
            List listaCliente = operacionesClientes.obtenerCliente(idCli);
            DefaultComboBoxModel modeloLocalidad = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
            if (listaCliente.size() > 0) {
                Iterator consulta = listaCliente.iterator();
                while (consulta.hasNext()) {
                    jtxtID.setText(String.valueOf(clientes.getClientesidCliente()));
                    jtxtNombreApellido.setText(clientes.getNombreApellido());
                    jdcFechaNacimiento.setDate(clientes.getFechaNacimiento());
                    this.validarSexoDesdeMySQL();
                    jdcFechaIngreso.setDate(clientes.getFechaIngreso());
                    jtaObjetivos.setText(clientes.getObjetivos());
                    jtxtPesoInicial.setText(String.valueOf(clientes.getPesoInicial()));
                    jtaLecturaCorporal.setText(clientes.getLecturaCorporal());
                    modeloLocalidad.addElement(new Localidad(localidad.getLocalidadidLocalidad(), localidad.getLocalidad()));
                    jcboLocalidad.setModel(modeloLocalidad);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encuentran registros.", "Registro", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se produjo el siguiente error: " + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

En el mismo JFrame tengo otro metodo que llamo desde el constructor del mismo para que al abrirse cargue los datos pasandole por parametro el **idClienteModificado** que es enviado al seleccionar la fila del JTable:

```
private void cargarDatos() {
        try {
            obtener(idClienteModificado);
            clientes.setNombreApellido(jtxtNombreApellido.getText());
            clientes.setFechaNacimiento(jdcFechaNacimiento.getDate());
            clientes.setSexo(this.sexo());
            clientes.setFechaIngreso(jdcFechaIngreso.getDate());
            clientes.setObjetivos(jtaObjetivos.getText());
            clientes.setPesoInicial(Float.parseFloat(jtxtPesoInicial.getText()));
            clientes.setLecturaCorporal(jtaLecturaCorporal.getText());
            clientes.setClientesLocalidadidLocalidad(this.localidad());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se han podido cargar los datos.\nEl tipo de error es:\n" + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda para identificar mi error, hace unos dias que ando con este error, muchas gracias.

Comment: Te sugiero asegurarte que tu conexion desde el ORM de Hibernate este conectado correctamente a la base de datos y luego pruebes que funcione correctamente la consulta de una tabla para asegurar que a ese nivel este bien. Posteriormente a un JFrame, para actualizar la vista te sugiero que hagas una clase que implemente las acciones de los botones de la misma para que desde alli luego de hacer la consulta refrezque la vista. Pero aqui lo crucial es el acoplamiento correcto de Hibernate. No se si estas usando maven o gradle para la misma.